# No Data while Hitting Salesforce Email Messages Soap API

Tags: python, salesforce, salesforce-lightning

I'm attempting to retrieve emails from my client's Salesforce account using the Soap API, but I'm encountering an issue with receiving an empty response. While there are both emails and events in their account, I can successfully retrieve events, but I'm unable to fetch emails.

Following is the api Which I am using

```
SELECT Id,ActivityId, BccAddress, TextBody, Status, Subject FROM EmailMessage.
```

Can anyone please let me know what I need to do to get emails.

Answer (score 0):

"Works for me". What are the permissions on the user you're logging in as. Is it a sysadmin or something lesser? Is the client's admin able to run this query fine in say Developer Console?

Not 100% sure what would you need, "Modify All Data" is bit overkill but "View All Data" or "View All: Cases" sounds tempting. When you view your user's profile in SF setup -> what do you see in Field Level Security for Email Message? https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.email_eds_perms.htm&type=5 doesn't help much

[image]

It's bit sledgehammer but I'd start with granting you a new permission set with View All Data and working back. Like maybe in the end your profile is fine but you're not allowed to see Cases that have emails -> so no emails either. Could be a sharing rule thing.

Comment: Hi @eyescream - I've verified that field permissions are already assigned, but I'm still unable to retrieve emails using python api. Are there any other settings that I might be overlooking?

Comment: There are some tips in https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.object_reference.meta/object_reference/sforce_api_objects_emailmessage.htm, search "Access to an email message depends on the associated object.". Ask admin whether it's Case or Task-related emails and they will have to experiment with granting you "View All Data", "View All: Case" etc (or sharing rules)

Comment: Okay, Let me check.

Comment: I didn't found any field Mentioned in Documentation i.e IsExternallyVisible, Do you where it's located.

Comment: What do you see in Setup -> Object Manager -> Email Message -> Fields? (/lightning/setup/ObjectManager/EmailMessage/FieldsAndRelationships/view). I wonder i it's something stupid like it's a sandbox, Setup -> Deliverability is set to no access and that causes some stuff to hide... Did they give you View All Data and still no luck?

Comment: Let me check that